# Download 64bit packages in a 32bit system

Tags: 11.04, package-management, architecture

I need to download some packages to install in my other machine which doesn't have internet access, and has a 64-bit architecture.

Since this machine which has internet connection is 32-bit, it only downloads 32-bit packages with apt-get.

I want to know if it is possible to:

1. download 64 bit packages;
2. download those which are already present.

Alternatively, is it possible to get the url for these packages in a automatic way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `aptitude` (to be installed):

```
sudo aptitude -o APT::Architecture="amd64" update
aptitude -o APT::Architecture="amd64" download package-name
```

(after that, remember to do an `apt-get update` without `-o` option, to restore correct i386 information).

It is also possible to show packages URLs with

```
apt-get --print-uris install package-name
```

but this only works for non inistalled packages. For 64 bits packages, change the suffix `_i386.deb` with `_amd64.deb`.

Alternatively,

```
apt-cache --no-all-versions show package-name | grep ^Filename
```

shows URL but without the leading server information. Server information can be obtained from:

```
apt-cache --no-all-versions policy package-name | 
    grep -A2 '^  [^ ]' | tail -1 | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

Comment: Perfect. I got to the --print-uris but since most packages were installed i wasn't getting anything. Thanks a lot!